# loading python when the linux kernel boots

Tags: python, linux-kernel

I was reading [This](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Python) and I was wondering if I could write an API in python or have python load in an init script. If this were to be possible would I need to edit the kernel's makefile?

Answer (score 5):

You can run python, or any other program, at boot, without needing to touch the kernel at all.  See the `init=` kernel command line parameter.

Comment: Looks like this was the same answer [last time someone asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392203/linux-kernel-that-runs-python-file-for-init).

Comment: It works, and it's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Well, have a look at [PerlLinux](http://perllinux.sourceforge.net/). It's a **toy** operating system with a Perl userland running on top of the Linux Kernel. I think they load a [ramdisk](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-initrd/index.html) during Init with the Perl environment running inside.

The real question is why would you wanna limit yourself to only having Python when Linux already offers Python + all the other tools and utilities?

Comment: This doesn't really help me. Also what do you mean when you say "Linux already offers Python + all the other tools and utilities"

Comment: @Coder404 I only brought up the link to present a possible approach - You'll have to look at the source and Makefiles yourself. The good news is, you don't have to change the Kernel. The bad news is there is no step by step tutorial I know of.