# Rolling your own init: How to shutdown/restart?

Tags: linux, shutdown, init, reboot

After reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45742/39407), I thought it would be funny to roll my own init on Python, so I wrote this in `/init-python`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import subprocess
# Make / writable!
subprocess.call(['/bin/mount', '-o', 'rw,remount', '/'])
# Became IPython (Now we're at it, get a good shell!)
os.execv('/usr/bin/ipython3', ['init'])
```

Then added `init=/init-python` to the `linux` line in GRUB config. It works.

So I was wondering now... how to power off or reboot my system with my homemade init?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with `reboot` function (`man 2 reboot`).

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll['libc.so.6']
RB_POWER_OFF = 0x4321fedc
RB_AUTOBOOT  = 0x01234567

def shutdown():
    libc.reboot(RB_POWER_OFF)

def reboot():
    libc.reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT)
```