# How do I initialize the framebuffer in my init executable?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, init

I have a "Minimal Linux" experiment where I have to take a system as close as possible to the bare kernel and thus I need to write my own `init`. I know how to do the shutdown, reboot, and console initialization, that `init` runs on PID 1 every time, and that it either initializes the framebuffer or has a script that does that. I am familiar with Linux, but there is no information on the internet for writing `init` except for an extremely minimal one that initializes the console, runs `printf` three times, and exits ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245247)) and a Python `init` in a shutdown/reboot question ([link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83049)). What I need is help with framebuffer initialization. My current code is below.

```c
int init_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // PID handler
    if (getpid() != 1)
    {
pidn1:  if (getppid() == 1)
        {
            execl("/sbin/initrq", "-i" 0);
            return;
        }
    }
    reboot(RB_DISABLE_CAD);
    // Console initialization
    int onefd = open("/dev/console", O_RDONLY, 0);
    dup2(onefd, 0); // stdin
    int twofd = open("/dev/console", O_RDWR, 0);
    dup2(twofd, 1); // stdout
    dup2(twofd, 2); // stderr
    if (onefd > 2) close(onefd);
    if (twofd > 2) close(twofd);
    // Print a message
    printf("CUSTOM LINUX INIT\nNo framebuffer init\n");
    // Run initrq.
    fork() // This forked copy will not be PID 1, so that receives an execl("/sbin/initrq", 0)
    if (getpid() != 1) goto pidn1; // Fork behavior independency
    // Create shutdown/reboot agent FIFO
    int fifofd = mkfifo("/etc/cinit-rs", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | IWOTH);
    uint8_t buf[2];
    // Main loop
    for (;;)
    {
        if (read(fifofd, buf, 2) < 2)
        {
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }
        if (buf[0] == 0x4A)
        {
            if (buf[1] == 0xF0)
            {
                init_shutdown(0);
            }
            if (buf[1] == 0xFF)
            {
                init_shutdown(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
void init_shutdown(int rscmd)
{
    execl("/sbin/initrq", rscmd ? "-r" : "-s", 0);
}
```

Let me clarify `initrq`. `initrq` is a process that runs `init` scripts defined using a specific method (the method is defined in the `initrq` implementation). If `initrq` receives `-i`, it runs startup scripts. If `initrq` receives `-s` or `-r`, it runs shutdown scripts, then shuts down or restarts depending on whether it's `-s` or `-r`, respectively.

Comment: The title of the question does not much the question. You should probably say what is the problem with your current code. An alternative approach to writing it yourself from scratch is to take the current working init code and work on it, removing unwanted functionality.

Comment: calling `system` from an `init` context, on a file system that has no shell yet? `man 3 system` will teach you that always fails, as `system` depends on `/bin/sh` existing. (it will also tell you *not* to use `system` for such problems, but plain `exec`/`execl`)

Comment: 1. I will fix the `system` calls now. 2. All that is missing from my `init` is framebuffer initialization.

Comment: Already fixed the `system` call.

Comment: This is not an `initrd` init, but rather a `/sbin/init`.